c# mvvm - Bind Model data to DialogBox Text
I'm trying to bind data from a model to the Text property of a TextBlock on a DialogBox, respecting (as far as possible) the mvvm pattern. But strangely, no text is displayed.
I have the same principle on a usercontrol which works perfectly.
ViewModel (VM_WizardPrestage)
LogEvents.Add("Server Name : " + Prestage.ServerName);
var dialog = new DialogBox(); // my original code
//var dialog = new DialogBox { DataContext = Prestage }; // @Clemens advice, to be tested by means of what I have to put in the constructor or in the xaml

bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();

Model (M_Prestage instantiated in Prestage)
public class M_Prestage
{
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
...
}

DialogBox Constructor
public DialogBox()
{
    // What can i do here ?
    InitializeComponent();
}

View
<Window x:Class="PRESTAGE.Views.DialogBox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PRESTAGE.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DialogBox" Height="150" Width="400" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="Transparent" ResizeMode="NoResize" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFECE1E1"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF022A79"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
                
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <Border  CornerRadius="12" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF022A79">
            <Border.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/banner_prestage.png"
                            Stretch="Uniform" Opacity="1"/>
            </Border.Background>
            <Border CornerRadius="10"                    
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Opacity="0.95">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0,5">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <StackPanel >
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Would you like to change the server name?" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF022A79"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Prestage.ServerName, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF022A79"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="48" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="242">
                            <Button x:Name="Oui" Width="226" Height="30" Content="OUI" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Cursor="Hand" Margin="0,0,9,0" Click="Oui_Click">

                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Border Width="73" Height="30" CornerRadius="10"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                            <ContentPresenter   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="158">
                            <Button x:Name="Non" Width="73" Height="30" Content="NON" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Cursor="Hand" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Non_Click">

                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Border Width="73" Height="30" CornerRadius="10"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                            <ContentPresenter   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>




            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Expected : i want to display in the DialogBox the data "ServerName" from Prestage Model.
Result : When the DialogBox is loaded, it does not display the server name. The frame is empty, so you can't see anything apart from the question and the buttons.
On the other hand, the Log does display this same Prestage.ServerName model data
Thank you in advance for your help

What exactly are you doing in the constructor of DialogBox?

Do you set Datacontext in constructor?

At first I thought I'd just put the data in the constructor parameter but I didn't know how to use it afterwards.
So I tried that, but without conviction.
public DialogBox() {     this.DataContext = new ViewModels.VM_WizardPrestage();     InitializeComponent(); }

That is a different constructor than the one called in new DialogBox(Prestage.ServerName).

Sorry, I forgot to remove my test by setting the data in the constructor parameter

So I've corrected my description in the post. So my problem must be related to a detail. Should you instantiate the Prestage model and not the ViewModel? (but if it's a new instance, you don't get the current data, do you?)
Or would it be good practice to place the data in the constructor parameter (but with a way of using it that I didn't have)?

"strangely, no text is displayed" - it is unclear why you expect anything to be displayed when you do not pass any data to the DialogBox. That does not make much sense.

If you want to pass the current view model instance to the DialogBox, you would write something like var dialog = new DialogBox { DataContext = this };. Be aware that this is not MVVM, and the DataContext assignment in the DialogBox constructor is obviously redundant.

Or var dialog = new DialogBox { DataContext = Prestage }; - not clear from your question.

Yes, sorry if my question is silly, I'm not a great expert in MVVM / WPF. In fact, I assumed that there was a way for the DialogBox to access model data directly (more or less implicitly) without knowing how to do it. But from your answer I guess that's no good. What would be MVVM best practice?

Search for "mvvm dialogservice". For "a way for the DialogBox to access model data directly" - that is what happens with var dialog = new DialogBox { DataContext = Prestage }; or similar. We do not know whether Prestage is a VM_WizardPrestage, so the details are up to you.

OK, so I ended up finding a good compromise with your indications.
I don't know why, but from the start I was trying to bind the Model data directly to the DialogBox view.
Probably because the application as I took it over is more of a very beginner MVVM (like me) and some data is often passed to the view directly from the instantiated Model, like Prestage.ServerName below
LogEvents.Add("Server Name: " + Prestage.ServerName);

By the way, I forgot that to be MVVM you first had to pass (correct me if I'm wrong) a ViewModel property.
So here are my functional modifications
ViewModel / adding ServerName property
public string ServerName
{
    get { return Prestage.ServerName; }
    set
    {
        Prestage.ServerName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ServerName));
    }
}

ViewModel / DialogBox instantiation
var dialog = new DialogBox { DataContext = this };
bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();

View / DialogBox
<StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ServerName, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF022A79"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>

That's it, unless it was related to the missing mode=TwoWay, in any case it works fine like that!
Thanks again for your comments
